# VB6 Returned Value from DateDiff

Tags: vb6, datediff

I have the If statement as below. If given values A and B as below, I wonder why the condition will be true in the end as the DateDiff will always return 0 and 0 is not larger than 100. I would appreciate for any comment.

```
A = ""
B = 100

If DateDiff("n", Me.A, Now()) > Val(Me.B) Then

End If
```

Comment: It is very easy to check: dim dateDiffResult as Long = DateDiff(...) and see what value it holds! I assume, that the function converts the empty string automatically to the youngest day possible and thus the difference between now and year 1 or something like this is a very big number and for sure greater than 100!

Comment: hi @pasty, I have tried with the code below and I always got 0 with the empty A variable.

Dim c As Integer
c = DateDiff("n", Me.A, Now())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datediff function returns the number of minutes since the start of the year 1900 which is a lot more than 100.

I couldn't get it to work with an empty string for A though

Comment: I was thinking like what you mentioned. And, I tried to debug with integer variable to hold the datediff, however I got 0 which is what I curious about.

Comment: Empty string A in datediff gives me an error. Integer variables initially hold a 0. Are you using on error resume next on the datediff by any chance? Maybe even a lot further earlier in the method?